# Cross-Site-Scripting(XSS) attempt from OpenID stackechange?

Tags: discussion

Today I was trying to login into stackechange that I ecounter the following problem.
My questions is, was someone trying to steal my session id? Do I have to worry about password of my email that was open in another tab? and the email and password that I used to login to my stackechange account.

NoScript is claiming that it blocked the attempt.

**if there is nothing to worry about,
why would NoScript block such attempt??**

Here is the screen shot of the problem:

[image]

Thank you for reading this!

Comment: NoScript’s XSS protection and ABE are terribad; ignore.

Comment: Rude.  *You're* terrible.

Comment: Migrating to meta, as this refers to the site itself.

Answer (score -1):

This is what we call in security: `False-positive.`, which is defined usually as a type of error that leads a protection application to conclude that a supposed attack or infection exists when in fact it doesn't.

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful when you would explain what might have triggered the detection and how to tell a false-positive apart from an actual attack.